# Sorting a 2 Dimensional Array by First Dimension (C)

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have a 2 dimensional array that I am trying to sort in ascending order. For example, say the array looks like this:

```
4, 5
2, 6
7, 2
8, 4
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
2, 6
4, 5
7, 2
8, 4
```

The code that I have so far:

```
int temp = 0;
for(int m = 0; m<=nonZeroLength-1; m++){
    for(int n = m+1; n<=nonZeroLength-1; n++){
        if(nonZeroScoreSorcting[m] > nonZeroScoreSorcting[m+1]){
            temp = nonZeroScoreSorcting[m];
            strcpy(nonZeroScoreSorcting[m], nonZeroScoreSorcting[n]);
            strcpy(nonZeroScoreSorcting[n], temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Assume that `nonZeroLength` has a value of 4 for this example. I am using `strcpy()` because I read that that is the only way to change elements of an array in C. When I run the program I get the following error:

> passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

I have also tried the regular assign method:

```
if(nonZeroScoreSorcting[m] > nonZeroScoreSorcting[m+1]){
    temp = nonZeroScoreSorcting[m];
    nonZeroScoreSorcting[m] = nonZeroScoreSorcting[n];
    nonZeroScoreSorcting[n] = temp;
}
```

Comment: `**I am using strcpy() because I read that that is the only way to change elements of an array in C. (Not sure if thats true though.) **` Definitely not true. What is the definition of `nonZeroScoreSorcting`. You say it's a 2D array but are using it like a 1D array.

Comment: In order to help us help you, you need to post a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are left guessing at what happens in the other areas of your code that will affect what our answer will be here. It your array is truly a 2D array of `int`, then `strcpy` is definitely wrong.

Comment: @David the other sections of my code are fine. The only thing i did not include was the deceleration of the 2D array as I have provided example contents for one in my question.

Comment: @ChristopherLittlewood - I've had to guess that you really have a 2D array of `int`, but presuming so, I've given a fairly complete explanation of row-sorting a 2D array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do in fact have a 2D array of `int` as you indicate, the key to sorting the array by row is understanding that during the sort, you will need to swap *rows*, not simply values. This is how you preserve the row-wise relationship during the sort.

You cannot do that treating each row of `int` as a *string* and attempting a row-wise copy using `strcpy`. This will result in *Undefined Behavior* when `strcpy` accesses values in the `src` argument outside the array bounds looking for a *nul-terminating* character that isn't present.

(though technically, providing a *properly sized array* for each `src` and `dest` and sizing `'n'` in `strncpy` to copy `2 * sizeof(int)` bytes can copy rows by virtue of limiting the read to `n` chars where no *nul-terminating* character is present -- but DON'T do it -- that's what `memcpy` (or `memmove`) is for).

Though the recommended way to sort in C is using the `qsort` function provided in `stdlib.h`, you can provide whatever sort algorithm you want. It will likely not be anywhere close to the efficiency of `qsort`, and certainly will be nowhere near as thoroughly tested. A simple row-sort using the slow old insertion sort could be done as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    int a[][2] = {{ 4, 5 },
                  { 2, 6 },
                  { 7, 2 },
                  { 8, 4 }},
        n = sizeof a / sizeof *a,
        col = sizeof *a / sizeof **a;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) /* insertion sort of a by row */
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && *a[j] < *a[j-1]; j--) {
            int tmp[col];   /* temporary VLA */
            memcpy (tmp, a[j], sizeof *a);
            memcpy (a[j], a[j-1], sizeof *a);
            memcpy (a[j-1], tmp, sizeof *a);
        }

    for (int (*p)[2] = a; p < a + n; p++)    /* output results */
        printf ("%d, %d\n", (*p)[0], (*p)[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/inssort2d
2, 6
4, 5
7, 2
8, 4
```

With `qsort` most new C programmers are stumped by having to write a *compare* function to pass to `qsort` to let it do its job. It is really not that difficult at all. You know `qsort` will pass pointers to two of whatever you are sorting as arguments to your compare function.

In this case you will be sorting rows of integers (1D arrays of integers) based on the first element of each row. So `qsort` will compare two `int *` (pointers to int). You only care about the first element in each array (which you can obtain simply by dereferencing the pointer). A compare here can be a simple:

```
int cmp (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    /* (a > b) - (a < b) */
    return (*(int *)a > *(int *)b) - (*(int *)a < *(int *)b);
}
```

(note: by using the result of the two inequalities you protect against over/underflow that could occur if you simply returned the result of a subtraction alone).

The complete `qsort` implementation would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    /* (a > b) - (a < b) */
    return (*(int *)a > *(int *)b) - (*(int *)a < *(int *)b);
}

int main (void) {

    int a[][2] = {{ 4, 5 },
                  { 2, 6 },
                  { 7, 2 },
                  { 8, 4 }},
        n = sizeof a / sizeof *a;

    qsort (a, n, sizeof *a, cmp);   /* qsort array of pointers */

    for (int (*p)[2] = a; p < a + n; p++)    /* output results */
        printf ("%d, %d\n", (*p)[0], (*p)[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

(output is the same)

Look over both methods and know that `qsort` is the preferred method, but for learning, there is nothing wrong with doing it by hand to gain experience. Let me know if you have further questions.